# Evenly distribute set into larger one

Tags: algorithm, r, interpolation, distribute

Can somebody point me to some reading on some algorithm that given a set n, will place it's elements in a bigger set m, evenly spaced (as much as possible). I plan to interpolate for the remaining values.

so I have a set of 3 elements which contains

```
    1 ,5 ,6
```

and I want to distribute it in a dataframe of 10 slots as evely as possible with the 1st and last elements being 1st and last accordingly in the new set:

```
    1 [] [] [] 5 [] [] [] [] 6
```

Thanks in advance.

PS. I am trying to achieve this with R

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly spaced"?  A set doesn't have a notion of "spacing".  Please edit your question to include an example.

Comment: Please, define set in your case. In most cases something defined as 'set' cannot be distributed or so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Comment: Thank you for offering your help. I have edited with a more concrete example.

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for, but maybe `approx` or `approxfun` will answer your underlying question more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the term "vector" which, in R anyway, has the notion of positions and length which are needed for this problem. (Mathematical sets are unordered, so have no positional interpretation and R does have set operators and functions.)

```
# Make up an empty vector:
vec <- vector("numeric", length=10)
# create a vector of items to place
 items <- c(1,5,6)
#Put the first one in the first empty "slot" and the last in the last/
 vec[1] <- items[1]
 vec[length(vec)] <- items[length(items)]
#Now find a positions for the remaining element(s)
 seq(1,length(vec), by=length(vec)/(length(items)-1))[-c(1,length(items))]
#[1] 6
# And place them (or it in this case) ....
  vec[ seq(1,length(vec), by=length(vec)/(length(items)-1))[
                        -c(1,length(items))] ] <- 
                              items[ -c(1,length(items)) ] 
 vec
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I considered answering your question but then I thought about the end goal and it seems to me that generating your vector with the smaller vector evenly distributed will not easily facilitate the interpolation.  The following gets you your interpolated vector.

```
bigLength <- 10
data <- c(1, 5, 6)
n <- length(data) - 1
breakLength <- bigLength / n
breaks <- floor(rep(breakLength+1, n))
breaks[1] <- breaks[1]-1
extra <- bigLength %% n
if (extra > 0) for(i in 1:extra) breaks[i] <- breaks[i]+1
y <- unlist ( lapply(1:n, function(i){ 
   y <- seq(data[i], data[i+1], length.out = breaks[i])
   return(y[-1])
   }) )
y <- c(data[1], y)
y
```

Answer (score 0):

Even thought the notion of a "set" is a little bit strange here, you might want to do something like histogram normalization (sometimes called contrast stretching) or histogram equalization.